# Erasing and syncing library in iPod Touch

Tags: windows-8, itunes, ipod-touch

I've formatted my computer recently (Windows 8). For some reason, I couldn't import my backed up `.itl` file.

I've decided it would be less trouble if I just made a new library and erased and synced the current one in my iPod. However, it tries to sync without erasing, which results in an error: `Cannot sync because at least 18 GB of free space is required`.

This had happened the last time as well. I'd resolved to erase the music on my iPod through its settings. It had erased it, *but* leaving the song names, etc. there. Although there wasn't any music left in it, iTunes perceived it to be full, and I could still see the song names in the iPod, but I couldn't play them.

I ended up having to restore the iPod, losing all app data (high scores that are not synced to gamecenter, preferences, etc.). I really don't want to go down that road again.

Why is nothing going as expected in iTunes? What is the safest way: the way in which I save most of my data?

Comment: Backup your iPod, then factory reset it, the restore the backup you made.

Comment: That erases some of the app data. That's what I did the last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck `Sync Music`, hit apply. This erases all the music successfully. Then, re-check `Sync Music`, and hit apply again. Wait for files to be transferred.

Since all the files have to be transferred, it lasts longer than it would if `erase and sync` had worked.